# automatic transfer to web page, via hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I want to be able to switch to a web page, as soon as I open a spreadsheet file, using the hyperlink. I don't want to click a hyperlink cell, but automatically transfer to the web page. Is this possible in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible; try using [VBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications).

Something like:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
    Const myLink As String = "http://www.SuperUser.com"
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=myLink, NewWindow:=True
End Sub
```

Open your workbook, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor, and add this code to the "This Workbook" module.

Anything inside the sub-routine "Wokrbook_Open" will run when the book is first opened.

Keep in mind you'll have to deal with the in-built Macro security in Office.